# How to determine who performed DROP/DELETE on Sql Server database objects?

Tags: sql-server

There is always a need to find out details, either intentionally Or mistakenly someone executed DROP/DELETE command on any of following SQL Server database objects.

1. DROPPED - Table from your database
2. DROPPED - Stored Procedure from your database
3. DELETED - Rows from your database table

Q. Is there TSQL available to find db user who performed DELETE/DROP?

Q. What kind of permissions are needed for user to find out these details?

Comment: DDL statements can be found in the default trace for a short period of time. If you want more control you need to create database triggers. Row deletion is not tracked at all. For that you would need to create a delete trigger. This question is very likely to get closed as being too broad.

Comment: well the purpose here is to trace such operations on database objects, say for example: someone dropped a stored procedure and we would like to know who did that.

Comment: You can take a look at [SQL Server Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine), but this won't give you info happened BEFORE the audit was in place. Also keep in mind that blaming somebody won't help. Please take care of proper backup strategies, disaster recovery plans and make sure, that the permissions on the server/databases are not too wide for the user.

Comment: Thanks @Pred, Audit will allow us to plan for future trace. I am more on looking for options to find out what had happend in past.

Comment: @SV : Kindly check my proposed answers

Comment: Thanks @PrabhatG I am giving it a try, the query seems promising, we definetly need to filter as I am more on consered about Deletion of rows and Stored procedure drop operations

Comment: @SV : I have commented out few columns. You may play with them for different results

Comment: Thx @PrabhatG both solutions are close to what I am looking for. Regarding query result for few rows the "ObjectName" is NULL where other columns doesnt gives any hints. Am researching more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check this ? 
Right click on database.
Go to as shown in image :
[image: sql server]

**Solution 2 :**
This query gives alot of useful information for a database(apply filter as required) :

```
DECLARE @filename VARCHAR(255) 
SELECT @FileName = SUBSTRING(path, 0, LEN(path)-CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(path))+1) + '\Log.trc'  
FROM sys.traces   
WHERE is_default = 1;  

SELECT gt.HostName, 
       gt.ApplicationName, 
       gt.NTUserName, 
       gt.NTDomainName, 
       gt.LoginName, 
       --gt.SPID, 
      -- gt.EventClass, 
       te.Name AS EventName,
       --gt.EventSubClass,      
      -- gt.TEXTData, 
       gt.StartTime, 
       gt.EndTime, 
       gt.ObjectName, 
       gt.DatabaseName, 
       gt.FileName, 
       gt.IsSystem
FROM [fn_trace_gettable](@filename, DEFAULT) gt 
JOIN sys.trace_events te ON gt.EventClass = te.trace_event_id 
WHERE EventClass in (164) --AND gt.EventSubClass = 2
ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
```

Comment: Use EventClass 47 for a deleted object.